# Problemas con Ajax.BeginForm Razor MVC4

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Buenos días. Ya había posteado anteriormente un problema con un formulario [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax), pero sigo sin poder concluir este módulo.
El problema es que cuando abro este `Formulario Ajax` (que se abre en un `dialog` y el `div` del mismo está fuera de cualquier otro formulario - está dentro del `layout`), agrego los datos y al hacer el submit pasa mas de 1 vez por la acción del `controller` (hasta 10 veces), como si se hubiese apretado el botón de submit muchas veces, y nunca me borra los datos de los `textbox`.

```
<div id='Div-AB-Email' style="display: none">
    <div id='Div-Email'></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function abrirFormEmail() {
    Preloader();
    preloaderBusquedas("Div-Email");

    $("#Div-AB-Email").dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        open: function (event, ui) {
            $("#Div-Email").load("/EmailPersona/Create");
            $("#Mail").val("");
            $("#Observaciones").val("");

        },
        focus: function (event, ui) { $("#Mail").focus(); },
        show: {
            effect: "blind",
            duration: 500,
        },
        hide: {
            effect: "blind",
            duration: 500
        },
        width: 1036,
        height: 400,
        title: "Email de contacto ",
        closeOnEscape: true,



    });

    PreloaderOff();
}
```

C#:

```
 public class EmailPersonaController : BaseController
{



    public PartialViewResult Create()
    {
        return PartialView();
    }



    [HttpPost]
    public PartialViewResult Create(EmailPersonaModel model)
    {
        if (model == null)
            return PartialView();

        if (model.IdPersona == 0)
        {

            model.IdPersona = ConsultaIdPersona();
            ModelState.Remove("IdPersona");
        }


        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                if (model.Nuevo())
                {
                    model.grabado = true;
                    ListItemsCarga().Add(model);
                    var modelnull = new EmailPersonaModel();
                    return PartialView(modelnull);
                }

                else
                {
                    return PartialView(model);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Mail))
                    TempData["ErrorEmail"] = "Debe escribir el mail que desea agregar a la lista";
            }
            return PartialView(model);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            if (e.Message == "ERROR: 23505: llave duplicada viola restricción de unicidad «uq_email_per»")
            {

               TempData["ErrorEmail"] = "El Mail que quiere cargar pertenece a otra persona";
            }

            return PartialView();
        }
    }
}
```

Razor:

```
@model QBOWEB3.Models.EmailPersonaModel
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "EmailPersona",
new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
   UpdateTargetId = "Div-Email"


}))  
{

    <fieldset>


            <h3>Email De Contacto</h3>
            <span>@ViewBag.Afiliado</span>
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)


            <legend>EmailPersonaModel</legend>



        <div id="contenidoEmail">

            <table class="TableCampsEdicion">

                <tr>

                    <td class="tdLabel">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Mail)
                    </td>

                    <td class="tdTextBox">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Mail)

                    </td>

                    <td class="tdLabel">


                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Observaciones)
                    </td>

                    <td class="tdTextBox">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Observaciones)

                    </td>

                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IdPersona)

                    <td class="tdTextBox">
                        <input type="submit" value="Agregar" class="botonAzulMediano" style="width: 95px; margin-left: 10px;" />

                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="tdTextBox" colspan="5">
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Mail)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Observaciones)
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>


        @*    <div id="itemsEmail">@Html.Action("Index")</div>*@

            @if (@TempData["ErrorEmail"] != null && @TempData["ErrorEmail"].ToString() != "")
            {
                <script>
                    $(function () {

                        mensaje("@TempData["ErrorEmail"]");


                    });
                </script>
            }
            @if (Model != null && Model.grabado)
            {
                <script>
                    $(function () {

                        $("#Mail").val("");
                        $("#Observaciones").val("");



                    });

                </script>



            }

            <script>
                $(function () {
                    $("#Mail").focus();
                    Enter_por_Tab();
                    PreloaderOff();


                })


            </script>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
}
```

Comment: entiendo que el view que nos muestras seria el partialview que se inyecta en el div del popup, no ? Si es asi la view principal donde esta esta partial tiene otro tag form, o sea hay forms anidados? porque si el div del popup define un form que hace submit y esta dentro de otro form de la view principal puede traer problemas

Comment: con que browser estas realizando la prueba? porque me sucedio algo parecido pero cuando depuraba desde el VS usando el IE, si cambio de browser ya no sucedia

Comment: La view principal tiene un Form. Pero el div del popUp lo coloque en el layout bien abajo, Debajo del footer.  Estoy probando con FirefoxDeveloper

Comment: También probé con Chrome

Comment: no evaluaste no usar Ajax.BeginForm y cambiarlo por $.ajax de jquery ? o sea invocar el action pero enviando los datos sin post al action, sino con una llamada ajax enviando json

Comment: Si, pero me trabe en como pasar el Modelo por ajax al controller. tendrás algún ejemplo?

Comment: como sugerencia ubicaría esto  `$("#Mail").val(""); $("#Observaciones").val("");`  dentro de una  _callback function_ en el load `.load()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como propuse en los comentarios se podria intentar cambiando e Ajax.BeginForm por una invocacion que use $.ajax de jquery.

Para enviar el form se podria usar el [.serialize()](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) de jquery sobre el `form`

[Web API With AJAX: Submit Form Data After Serialization](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dacca2/web-api-with-ajax-submit-form-data-after-serialization/)

En el ejemplo se observa que usa `data: $('#form1').serialize(),` para enviar los datos del `form` al action del controller

```
$("#Save").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("NombreAction")',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: $('#form1').serialize(),
            success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(textStatus);
            }
        });
});
```

Pero no defienas un Ajax o Html BeginForm en el partialview, sino usa el tag `form` como `html`.

**>>En la acción create del controller ¿que debería retornar?**

El retorno depende, algunos devuelven un json 
o un [HttpStatusCodeResult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5072804/how-to-return-a-200-http-status-code-from-asp-net-mvc-3-controller)  indicando un `Ok` de `http`
Pero tambien podria ser un void o un valor simple como string o bool

Comment: En la acción create del controller ¿que debería retornar?. Lo estoy probando. Llega al método create, el Model llega bien. pero al retornar al método de Ajax entra en error. Imagino que es por el retorno